# CSS3 Transition/Transform returns an error I can't make sense of

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

thanks for the help.

I'm playing around with CSS3 Transitions, and I'm trying to apply a transition to a DIV when the submit button on a form is clicked.  The code I have is below, as well as the error message I get in JSfiddle. In a browser, there's no transition it just goes to its final destination immediately.

http://jsfiddle.net/2mMV5/

```
<div id="signup">
        <p>Sample text</p>

        <form action="#signup" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
            <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="GO!">
        </form>
</div>

#signup {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -200px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.01);
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5), 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.15) inset;
    transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#signup:target{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);

}
```

And here's the error message I get:

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x266e910>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x266e8d0>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x266e910>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x2665590>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

Comment: You're attacking this from the wrong direction.  Can you explain exactly what result you're hoping for?  Do you want it to turn like a wheel 180 deg, flip on itself like folding paper til it's upside down, use the baseline as an anchor and swing downward, etc?

Comment: Hhmm okay.  I'm trying to make it turn 180 degrees over the Y axis.  This code works totally fine when I change it to #signup:hover, but when I try to target it so that when I click the submit button it transforms, I get the above error.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're receiving is only because that site places the rendered page into its own little **cage** and you're trying to open a page that isn't actually there since that **cage** is made from scratch on each load.  I believe it's a security measure for the site to prevent a possible overflow *(something like a javascript `for()` infinite loop reloading the page to itself, for instance).*

I have placed the exact code you posted **[here on my server](http://1054.fleeceitout.com/test.html)** and it works as you describe.

Comment: Thanks Deryck.  So I'm confused, why is it working just fine on your server but not locally on my computer or in JSFiddle?

Comment: On fiddle it's basically trapping it and ignoring the form submission.  I'm not entirely sure why it wouldn't work on your computer...open it on my server, right click the page and click 'Save As' and then open the file on your desktop and see what happens